# If two solutions of arg$(z)$ are in interval $−\pi<$arg$(z)≤\pi$ are both correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

For example there is complex number $z=\sqrt3-i$
Are the answers $\frac{5}{6}\pi$ and $-\frac{\pi}{6}$ correct as $\text{arg}(z)$?

Comment: No.  Draw a picture and you should easily see which one is correct.

Comment: When writing $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$, it is necessary for $|z|geq 0$.